# Rename images in database to md5 but keep extensions

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says I'm wanting to change the image names stored in a database to md5 but keep the image extension, I had a go with the code below but it failed (probably due to the fact I haven't a clue what I'm doing) ...any ideas on how I could achieve my goal?

```
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
  return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}

$query  = "SELECT img FROM post";
$result = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   $name   = substr($row['img'], -4, 4);
   $ext    = get_file_extension($row['img']);
   $notmd5 = $row['img'];
   $md5img = md5($name).'.'.$ext;

 $q = "UPDATE post SET img='$md5img' WHERE img='{$notmd5}'";
 $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

..........................................................

***Update***

***Answer:***

Rename files in dir/folder and db names at same time:

```
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
  return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}

//path to directory to scan
$directory = "thumbs/";
 $directory2 = "md5/";
//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.*");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
$imag = str_replace($directory, '', $image);
$ex   = get_file_extension($imag);

$new = md5($imag).'.'.$ex;

rename($image, $directory2.$new);

 $q = "UPDATE post SET img='$new' WHERE img='{$imag}'";
 $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

When I originally asked my question I had already renamed the images in dir/folder but I had a backup of them so mixed the to jobs together and got my goal :)

Comment: How it failed? Any errors? not the expected output? Please explain.

Comment: Why not split the image name string by `.` and store the name and extension in two different fields, then concatenate them on retrieval?

Comment: the substr method is not going to work with files that have multiple periods so unless you're validating your input that's likely to cause some problems.

Comment: Mahmoud: It changed all to same md5 name. Zak: Some names contain dots/periods so can not use `explode()`

Comment: Anna, What about separating $name and $ext and doing the following? `"UPDATE post SET img='" . md5($name) . "', ext='" . $ext . "' WHERE img='{$notmd5}'"`

Comment: >Noting posted solution<  Looks like the _bug_ in the original code was that call to substr that was returning the file extension instead of the name..

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend a batch update like this just be done with pure SQL, especially if the business logic is as simple as this, it can all be done natively in MySQL for sure.

Anyway.., one thing that pops out is the `substr` call to get the `$name` of the file, it's hardcoded to get only 4 characters and it's actually getting the extension not the name.

Try this instead:

```
$ext = get_file_extension($row['img']);  // get ext first

// use length of $row['img'] - length of file extension to extract name
substr($row['img'], 0, strlen($row['img']) - strlen($ext) - 1);
```

Comment: Actually I realize there's a call to `rename` the file on disk.  Almost seems nice to have it running in the PHP in light of that.  Building a batch update and running it in a single loop after the query would be recommended though, instead of looping and running all those single updates.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in pure SQL:

```sql
UPDATE post SET img = CONCAT_WS('.',
  MD5(TRIM(TRAILING CONCAT('.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(img, '.', -1)) FROM img)),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(img, '.', -1)
)
```